# adding a references folder to a project VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll, reference

I have two dll files which should be always in the bin/debug folder at runtime, I can add one of them as a reference, but the other one gives an error about that it is not being accessible, but whenever I added to the bin/debug file manually it works fine.

What I want to do now is I created a Lib folder which contains the two dll files, but I want to the whole folder as a reference so whenever the project runs the folder is directly linked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't reference a directory, you can reference a project - I suspect this is what you want.  That should also resolve itself as you update the binaries.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have another file being copied to the bin folder of your project, add the file to your project, go to properties set `Copy to Output Directory` to Copy Always

Comment: I put them in a folder, and then foreach of these two I set the copy to output to "Copy Always", but both of them now in a folder called "bin/debug/myFolderName", and they are not being read of course because they are not directly in the debug folder, is there anyway to make them accessible while being in that folder(myFolderName)?

Comment: don't add the folder to your project, just put the dll into the root of your project, this should copy it into bin/debug directly

Comment: I am required to have it not in the root to make the project "LESS MESSY" thats why I was wondering if reaching the file inside the other folder is possible

Comment: no, chances are very high the dll you mentioned is a requirement for/linked by some other dll, right? So if this other dll doesn't find it within the same folder, it will not work...

Comment: Alternatively you can physically add the dll to a solution folder and add only a **link** of it to your project. This means, the dll is not really located within your project, it just appears in VS Solution Explorer and can be used during build. Don't know if this would be less messy in your terms ^^

Comment: Actually it is not my term :P I am only an intern xD

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add the link?

Comment: right click the project, add > Existing Item, select the dll, do not click add, click the small arrow and select "Add as link"

Comment: I thought this was no longer available in vs2012?

Comment: It is (I have vs2013)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting "Copy local" for this dlls to true?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is add the the two dlls to your solution as content, and then set both to copy to output directory set to true.  You can do this by looking at the properties of the included dll.